# Aws s3 bucket delete object not working cause 403 access denied

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i am deleting object in s3 bucket but it's showing this error

DELETE (URL) 403 (Forbidden)
Uncaught (in promise) AccessDenied: Access Denied

this is my s3 bucket policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1643194772258",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1628194965425",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MY_BUCKET_NAME/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

++ other method working well! (copyObject)

Comment: You may have explicit deny in some other policy, e.g. user or group IAM, or public access settings enabled. But anyway, this is very terrible and dangerous bucket policy to have. You shoudn't use such a policy ever.

Comment: This policy allows anyone in the world (eg me!) to write objects to your bucket, list the contents of your bucket, download files from the bucket and delete objects from the bucket. Is this your intention?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1643194772258",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1628194965425",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::MY_BUCKET_NAME",
                         "arn:aws:s3:::MY_BUCKET_NAME/*"],
        }
    ]
}
```

Try this should work.